# Pressing and Holding windows key

Tags: windows-10-mobile, nokia-lumia-535, navigation-key

When I press and hold the windows key in my lumia 535 (W10M-RM-1090) screen goes half and no matter which app I do open; the screen remains half.See the screenshot

[image]

Tapping on that empty space reverts screen to its normal size. When I was on W8.1 nothing happened on holding windows key. Any solution?  My phone is 535 DS running W10M (build 10.0.14393.693) if relevant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a new feature in Windows 10 Mobile called one-handed mode. It's designed to help people using larger-screened phones reach the top of the display better (e.g. to open action centre). If you dislike this feature, simply don't tap-and-hold on the Windows key.

For more information about one-handed mode, see [this article at Windows Central](http://www.windowscentral.com/how-use-one-handed-mode-windows-10-mobile).

Comment: Oh wow! I thought as if it were a bug. Or phone wants to show something but is unable to do so.................Well thanks

Comment: You can resume to the normal screen mode by pressing the black part, or not touching the screen for four seconds

Comment: You can also resume normal screen mode by long-pressing the windows key again.

Comment: Thanks to you all....because of your efforts now I know more than anyone else about reachability feature in windows 10 mobile.